# FreeBSD core dump file permissions

Tags: freebsd, core-dump

Is there a way to specify the core dumped file permissions?

When I use `sysctl` these are the variables I see.

```
kern.corefile: /var/coredump/%N.core
kern.nodump_coredump: 0
kern.coredump: 1
kern.capmode_coredump: 0
kern.sugid_coredump: 1
debug.ncores: 5
debug.elf32_legacy_coredump: 0
debug.elf64_legacy_coredump: 0
```

These are all configured to properly dump cores into the /var/coredump directory. However, I don't see any way to specify the permissions of the file.

Off the top of my head, I can run a script via root's crontab to change the permissions on that directory every 1m. However, that doesn't seem like a proper solution.

Is there a way to properly change the core file permissions?

Comment: You can edit and recompile the kernel. In 10.3, the code is in `kern/kern_sig.c`. Look for `cmode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks for the tip. A `sysctl` variable would definitely have been easier, but that should work. If you submit as an Answer I can check your answer off (once I compile and verify later this morning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the present time, the kernel will always create a core file with 0600 permissions; it's hard-coded in the C source.

If you can rebuild your kernel, the line to change is in `kern/kern_sig.c` (in 10.3 and 11.0), in the function `corefile_open()`:

```
cmode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
```